# why bcrypt in nodejs show different result from online encryption tools using same encryption method

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

In nodejs, I am using bcrypt to encode my password:

```
bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null)
```

but looks like what put in the database is different from what I got encrypt using an online tool with same bCrypt, hash and salt (as attached image)
My password use for this test: Password123,
(the encryption I got in the database the lower windows address bar, while the upper window shows the test online encryption tool with different result.)
[image]

Comment: you will get different result even you run on same computer every time

Comment: then I wonder how could the computer knows that I have correct login ? I mean if I put the same password at login but it always give different output every time as you say above then how to compare ?

Comment: don't know the exact algorithm, but you can check the password with `bcrypt.compare`

Comment: Yes, I am using it, but I don't understand the principle, since I do the comparison by my self and got different results